# In a Wayland session, how to automatically disable input devices when the laptop lid is closed?

Tags: wayland, xinput, libinput

Running X11 I could install acpid and modify the /etc/acpi/handler.sh script to use xinput to do the deed:

```
    button/lid)
    case "$3" in
        close)
            #set variables so xinput can access the desktop session
            XAUTHORITY=/home/netsplit/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xinput disable 10
            XAUTHORITY=/home/netsplit/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xinput disable 11
            logger 'LID closed'
            ;;
        open)
            XAUTHORITY=/home/netsplit/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xinput enable 10
            XAUTHORITY=/home/netsplit/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xinput enable 11
            logger 'LID opened'
```

However xinput isn't for Wayland. Also xauthority isn't relevant to Wayland either. I looked at libinput but it doesn't seem to provide a means to disable/enable things from the shell.

Sleep isn't an option because I prefer to manually enable sleep. Sometimes I leave my laptop doing stuff with the lid closed.

Sometimes the trackpad and keyboard with be going off with the lid closed, so come back to a bunch of text and windows. Under X disabling them when the lid was closed fixed that. Trying to get Wayland working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution that should work on more than just Plasma and Wayland.

Linux 5.11 added an [inhibited](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.11-Inhibited-Input) property to input devices that does just what I want.

All I had to do was:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | more
```

Then look for the input device Sysfs=... values.

For example the keyboard was:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event3 rfkill 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=20000 20 0 0 1100f02100000 3803078f900d401 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3 tells me that if I write a 1 to /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/inhibited, then the kernel will disable keyboard input. That would be pretty hard to fix without a reboot, so be careful about doing that.

Likewise the touchpad had a value Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8. Same thing. echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/inhibited will disable the touchpad.

Having those pieces here's how to do it.

Install acpid (exact command depends on your package manager)

modify /etc/acpi/handler.sh to be something like this near the bottom. You may need to change the paths if your sysfs values are different for your input devices:

```
button/lid)
    case "$3" in
        close)
    echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/inhibited 
    echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/inhibited
            logger 'LID closed'
            ;;
        open)
    echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/inhibited
    echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/inhibited
            logger 'LID opened'
            ;;
        *)
            logger "ACPI action undefined: $3"
            ;;
```

For reference my complete /etc/acpi/handler.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Default acpi script that takes an entry for all actions

case "$1" in
    button/up)
;;
    button/down)
;;
    button/right)
;;
    button/left)
;;
    button/power)
        case "$2" in
            PBTN|PWRF)
                logger 'PowerButton pressed'
                ;;
            *)
                logger "ACPI action undefined: $2"
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    button/sleep)
        case "$2" in
            SLPB|SBTN)
                logger 'SleepButton pressed'
                ;;
            *)
                logger "ACPI action undefined: $2"
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    ac_adapter)
        case "$2" in
            AC|ACAD|ADP0)
                case "$4" in
                    00000000)
                        logger 'AC unpluged'
                        ;;
                    00000001)
                        logger 'AC pluged'
                        ;;
                esac
                ;;
            *)
                logger "ACPI action undefined: $2"
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    battery)
        case "$2" in
            BAT0)
                case "$4" in
                    00000000)
                        logger 'Battery online'
                        ;;
                    00000001)
                        logger 'Battery offline'
                        ;;
                esac
                ;;
            CPU0)
                ;;
            *)  logger "ACPI action undefined: $2" ;;
        esac
        ;;
    button/lid)
        case "$3" in
            close)
        echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/inhibited 
        echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/inhibited
                logger 'LID closed'
                ;;
            open)
        echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/inhibited
        echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/inhibited
                logger 'LID opened'
                ;;
            *)
                logger "ACPI action undefined: $3"
                ;;
    esac
    ;;
    *)
        logger "ACPI group/action undefined: $1 / $2"
        ;;
esac

# vim:set ts=4 sw=4 ft=sh et:
```